# Return custom XML from Web Api C# with "DOCTYPE"

Tags: c#, xml, asp.net-mvc, service, asp.net-web-api2

```
<!DOCTYPE ivr_info SYSTEM 'https://192.168.1.96/xml/ivr.dtd'>
            <response>
             <result>
               <ivr_info>
                 <variables>
                   <variable>
                     <name>balance</name>
                     <value>12323</value>
                   </variable>      
                 </variables>
               </ivr_info>
             </result> 
            </response>
```

I want sample XML response from web api as above format with Document Type i.e

```
 <!DOCTYPE ivr_info SYSTEM 'https://192.168.1.96/xml/ivr.dtd'>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to add an XDocumentType to the beginning of the XDocument:

```
var xDocument = new XDocument(
  new XDocumentType(
    "ivr_info SYSTEM",
    "https://192.168.1.96/xml/ivr.dtd",
    null
  ),
  new XElement("Root")
);
```